# Extracting sub-strings with Stream in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to Streams and Lambdas in Java. I have a variable like this  -

```
 List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("ab,12,bd","df,23,df","ef,98,dg");
```

I wanted these actions to happen.

1. Split each element in the list.
2. Extract 2nd element in the resulting array. (that is numbers).
3. Apply some function on it. To make it simple, let's I wanted to multiply it by 2.
4. Then collect the result as list, that is list containing 24,46,196.

   I tried doing that in streams, but I'm not able to get. Any pointers will be helpful. Thank you.

**Edit:** I tried this way and got result -

```
    List<Integer> result1 = lines.stream()
                            .map(l -> l.split(",")[1])
                            .map(l->Integer.parseInt(l))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And got results as

```
[12, 23, 98]
```

Is this is correct way of doing stream?

Comment: Please show your current attempt to better illustrate your description .

Comment: Tried something? Share it, that helps understand what you're not able to resolve.

Comment: Have added my code..

Comment: this is absolutely correct for your input, yes. small caveat to replace `l->Integer.parseInt(l` with a method reference: `Integer::parseInt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be straightforward.

```
lines.stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split(",")[1]) * 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Update** based on the updated question

> Is this is correct way of doing stream?

Yes. You can further combine the two `map` operations into one like I have shown above.

Comment: Using split() method here is less performant than just using a regex because it creates an extra array with all elements when we want just one.

Comment: @Tet: you can specify a limit to `split` to avoid unnecessary work. In that case, it might be even more efficient than regex, as `String.split` has a fast path for single char patterns. But if performance really matters, writing a dedicated method using `indexOf` and `substring` might be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work for you?

```
lines.stream().map(s -> s.split(",")[1])
     .map(Integer::parseInt)
     .map(f)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where `f` is your function from `Integer` to the type you want to use in your final list.

Comment: Using split() method here is less performant than just using a regex because it creates an extra array with all elements when we want just one element.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
List<Integer> result = lines.stream()
    .map(line -> line.replaceFirst(".*,(\\d+),.*", "$1"))
    .map(num -> 2 * Integer.parseInt(num))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You may want to convert to `int[]` in that case you can use:

```
int[] result = lines.stream()
    .map(line -> line.replaceFirst(".*,(\\d+),.*", "$1"))
    .mapToInt(num -> 2 * Integer.parseInt(num))
    .toArray();
```